# mod_rewrite - add www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force `www` for my site address with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.coml/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I open `mysite.com` this working ok - it adds `www`. It becomes `http://www.mysite.com/index.php`.

But if I open `mysite.com/subpage` I redirected to `http://www.mysite.com/index.php` again, instead of `http://www.mysite.com/subpage`.

But if I open `http://www.mysite.com/subpage` I don't get redirect (which is the expected behaviour).

How can I fix this? I would like the redirect all requests to my site to the `www` subdomain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

`^` specifies the beginning of the string while `$` specifies the end.

In order to make it work you need to have a wildcard select after the .com or `.+`.

to reiterate what Alex said:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 18):

From the superb [HTML5 Boilerplate `.htaccess`](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I have to disagree with Mr. Szanto.

It would appear the problem was not with the:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

Through some additional research (via Google) I found that this worked great for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Mr. Szanto's answer, while well formatted, seems to redirect all requests missing the 'www' to be redirected with the 'www' attached. This was not a desirable outcome with most subdomains. The above code only redirects if there is no 'www' AND no subdomain before the TL domain name.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I liked above answer the most -- anyone using sub-domains has to be more specific not to append www needlessly (and incorrectly).