# Using modrewrite to rewrite multiple urls

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, rule

If such a request comes from web.website.com or web.com, I want it to be redirected to http://www.web.com. I want to use the RewriteCond only once. How would I do that?

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493241/mod-rewrite-add-www

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way

Comment: I want only 1 rewrite rule and note it is website.com and web.com