# htaccess redirect non www to www URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am running Magento site and in my `.htaccess` file I use this peace of code to redirect non `www` to `www` URL but it does nothing.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My URL also contains HTTPS with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite - add www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493241/mod-rewrite-add-www)

Comment: Duplicate question. Asked and Answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This....

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
 Rewriterule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic domains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```